# Display xml on a <textarea>(or <pre>) and highlight parts of xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that displays the xml on a `<textarea>` using - `$("#xmltextarea").val( xml code here );`.

This puts the xml onto the value attribute like - `<textarea value="xml code here"></textarea>` 
and not like - `<textarea> xml code here </textarea>`.

This gives me a problem where by I could not highlight a part of the xml code, since one of the jQuery plugin, jQuery highlightTextarea's requirement is to have - `<textarea> xml code here </textarea>`.

I tried multiple ways to using `$("#xmltextarea").html( xml code here );` or `$("#xmltextarea").text( xml code here );`, but apparently it does not show the xml tags on the textarea. I even tried to use `<pre>` tag, but it appears to behave the same way as textarea. How do I make a text box that displays the xml codes, and at the same time displays the tags properly with some highlighting on some parts of xml?

Comment: `<textarea>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. Where did you see the code `<textarea value="xml code here"></textarea>`?

Comment: hmm i tried using `$("#xmltextarea").val( xml code here );`. The XML code show up on the textarea box but it doesn't appear in between `<textarea>` tag on the Inspect Element. In fact the Element tab does not even show where the xml code was placed, but somehow the xml was displayed on the textarea box. Hence, I thought that there is an attribute that holds the xml code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of val, try html - like this -

```
       <textarea id="xmltextarea"></textarea>

       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var xml = "<student> abcd </student>\n";
            $("#xmltextarea").html( xml );

       });
        </script>
```